# php curl Able to login into site but shows no data after login

Tags: php, curl

HI,

I am able to login into the site using php and curl. but when i try to read the data after logging in it shows  string(0) ""  if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER enabled and when disabled it shows bool(true). I dont understand where exactly i am going wrong...

any help is really appreciated

heres code

```
$cookie_file_path = "C:\\Apache2\\htdocs\\test.txt";


//$fp = fopen($cookie_file_path,'wb');   
//fclose($fp);

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/3.6.0";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://kinray.com/redirector1/weblink.jsp");   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_fie_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//Do not print anything now. 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "custId=XXXXX&passWord=YYYYY");

$html = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(urlencode($html));

 curl_close();
 $ch1 = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,"https://kinray.com/weblink2/search/categories.do?scrollType=&code=&alwaysCustomerNumber=023987");   
   curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_fie_path);
   curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
   curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
   //curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   //curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   $html2 = curl_exec($ch1);
   curl_close();
   echo "<hr>";
   var_dump( $html2);
```

Any clue where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should these variables be different?

```
//                                              v
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_fie_path);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file_path);
//                                              ^
```

It may be that your cookies aren't being stored/retrieved properly.

#### [httpRequest Class](http://www.dereleased.com/httpRequest.php) Example (short form static constructors):

```
$loginAttempt = httpRequest::post(
        'https://kinray.com/redirector1/weblink.jsp',
        'custId=XXXXX&passWord=YYYYY'
    )
    ->ignoreSSL()
    ->setCookieJar($cookie_file_path)
    ->retrieveHeader()
    ->setManualOption(CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com")
    ->splode(); // executes the request
// you can get to the returned value with $loginAttempt->responseRaw,
// or a host of other options, see __get()

$loggedInPage = httpRequest::get('https://kinray.com/weblink2/search/categories.do?scrollType=&code=&alwaysCustomerNumber=023987')
    ->ignoreSSL()
    ->setCookieJar($cookie_file_path)
    ->splode();
```

you can easily get to the response body by accessing the body property (`$loggedInPage->body`, for example) from there.  Let me know if this works for you.

EDIT: Sample Response

```
<script>document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false;};</script>
<!--categories.jsp-->
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/weblink2/styles.css">
<script>
   
   
   
















top.frames.search.setPaging('up'  , true);
top.frames.search.setPaging('down', true);


   var categories  = [ 
   
   ["27","BABY DIAPERS                                      "],
   
   ["28","BABY FORMULA                                      "],
   
   ["66","BAG STUFFER (PG)                                  "],
   
   ["90","BAG STUFFER FLYER DECEMBER                        "],
   
   ["89","BAG STUFFER FLYER NOVEMBER                        "],
   
   ["78","BAG STUFFER WINDOW SIGNS DECEMBER                 "],
   
   ["77","BAG STUFFER WINDOW SIGNS NOVEMBER                 "],
   
   ["35","BATTERIES                                         "],
   
   ["17","BONUS , VALUE PACKS                               "],
   
   ["22","CANDY AND GUM                                     "],
   
   ["49","CANDY AND GUM - SUGARFREE                         "],
   
   ["25","COSMETICS                                         "],
   
   ["52","COUGH &amp; COLD LIQUIDS                              "],
   
   ["21","DIABETIC NEEDS                                    "],
   
   ["42","DIAGNOSTICS                                       "],
   
   ["16","DISPLAYS, FLOORSTANDS                             "],
   
   ["33","ELECTRONICS                                       "],
   
   ["43","ETHNIC                                            "],
   
   ["26","FAMILY PLANNING                                   "],
   
   ["44","FILM, CAMERAS, &amp; VIDEO                            "],
   
   ["32","FOOD ITEMS                                        "],
   
   ["5","FRAGRANCES MEN                                    "],
   
   ["45","FRAGRANCES WOMEN                                  "],
   
   ["54","GENERIC ANTIBIOTICS                               "],
   
   ["13","GENERIC SPECIALS                                  "],
   
   ["53","GENERIC TOPICALS                                  "],
   
   ["8","GENERICS NEW                                      "],
   
   ["7","HBA\&#039;S NEW                                         "],
   
   ["41","HOME APPLIANCES                                   "],
   
   ["3","HOME HEALTH CARE                                  "],
   
   ["14","HOME HEALTH CARE (NEW)                            "],
   
   ["4","HOME HEALTH CARE MONTHLY SPECIALS                 "],
   
   ["93","HOME HEALTH CARE TOP 40                           "],
   
   ["36","HOMEOPATHIC                                       "],
   
   ["31","HOUSEHOLD GOODS                                   "],
   
   ["9","INJECTABLES                                       "],
   
   ["29","INSULIN                                           "],
   
   ["50","NEVER OUT OF STOCK ITEMS                          "],
   
   ["30","NUTRITIONALS                                      "],
   
   ["56","OTC PRODUCTS CONTAINING PSE                       "],
   
   ["46","PERSONAL CARE APPLIANCES                          "],
   
   ["51","PET SUPPLIES                                      "],
   
   ["59","PHARMACY FIRST                                    "],
   
   ["40","PHARMACY SUPPLIES (MISC)                          "],
   
   ["55","PRE-BOOK ITEMS                                    "],
   
   ["20","PREFERRED PLUS (KPP) NEW                          "],
   
   ["2","PREFERRED PLUS (P/L) KPP                          "],
   
   ["10","RX BAGS (PHARMACY SUPPLIES)                       "],
   
   ["12","RX SPECIALS                                       "],
   
   ["6","RX\&#039;S NEW                                          "],
   
   ["24","SCHOOL SUPPLIES                                   "],
   
   ["15","SUMMER                                            "],
   
   ["60","SUNGLASSES/EYEGLASSES                             "],
   
   ["47","SYRINGES, NEEDLES, ACCESSORIES                    "],
   
   ["34","TOYS &amp; GAMES                                      "],
   
   ["18","TRIAL &amp; TRAVEL SIZES                              "],
   
   ["39","VIALS &amp; BOTTLES (PHARMACY SUPPLIES)               "],
   
   ["23","VITAMINS                                          "],
   
   ["37","WETS &amp; DRYS                                       "],
   
   ["",""]
   
   ];
   
   var titleSearch='';

   function DisplayCategories (table) {
      document.write("<TABLE class=searchTable border =0  cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=0 >");
      var k=0;
      for(var x=0; x<=(table.length-1); x++) {
         if(x%20==0)
            document.write("<TD>");
         document.write("<a href =\"javascript:parent.parent.frames.search.loadCategory(categories["+x+"][0], categories["+x+"][1])\">",table[x][1],"</a><BR>");
      }
      document.write("</TABLE>");
   }
   
   DisplayCategories(categories);
   top.setKeyHandlers(document);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: cookies are generating perfectly.. I did check the file. I've posted code below my post in case you want to check out.

Comment: Except, if you look at it again, the cookies are not being loaded on the second request due to the mistyped variable name.  `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` is pointing to an undeclared variable.  They would, however, be being saved correctly because the variable name is NOT mistyped for `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.

Comment: ok with this one http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9198104/index3.php I get headers but no body :(

Comment: What is the value of the Content-Length header?

Comment: I have a fairly well tested freeware class that abstracts the cURL portion away in favor of the idea of making an http request.  I'll post a link to the source in a moment.

Comment: http://dereleased.com/httpRequest.php -- hopefully the documentation makes enough sense but I'll post examples of how to do what you want to do in my answer.

Comment: My answer is updated to reflect a link to the class and some examples.

Comment: if i do $loginAttempt->__get("responsebody") first $loginAttempt works out and page redirects. if i comment it there is no output. (I do write $LoggedInPage->__get("responsebody") but no output)

Comment: can you post the value of `$loggedInPage->responseHeader`?

Comment: also, __get is a magic method, you can call those values directly, e.g. `$loginAttempt->responseBody` instead of ` $loginAttempt->__get("responsebody")`

Comment: var_dump($loggedInPage->responseHeader); ===> NULL

Comment: use this path: `https://kinray.com/weblink2/user/login.do` and this parameter string: `'callType=login&custId=' . $username . '&passWord=' . $password` And see if `$loggedInPage->body` is populated.

Comment: In my tests it's there, but nothing is between the '<body></body>' tags, so I'm not sure what to do for you beyond this.  Good Luck.

Comment: could you please drop the entire file?

Answer (score 2):

Your `curl_close` calls are broken.  Pass in the curl resource.  E.g.:

```
curl_close($ch);
```

This is why you should enable and pay attention to warnings.

```
php > curl_close();
PHP Warning:  curl_close() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in php shell code on line 1
```

This in turn means your cookie jar won't work properly.

Comment: tried out closing curl. nothing changed at all. and in my opinion it has nothing to do with curl_close() because those are entirely different requests and they are sharing one cookie file.

Comment: @Vincent, per the docs, the cookie jar is written "when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close."  So even if it isn't the current issue, failing to call `curl_close` properly will probably bite you eventually.

Comment: Sorry.. got your point. If cookie is not released on time then it wont work on second time and the page will again ask for username and password

Comment: Now I closed handle and commented out lines with CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER but now it started to txfer to the  login success page after execution of first block. strange thing.. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you are having issues with curl, use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to help you debug.

Do the request using your browser, and inspect the traffic, then do it in curl and compare. That will tell you what is different.

Comment: Actually I did inspect trafic. but theres nothing unusual. Cookies are generating. and I am sharing the same cookie with two calls. so ideally it should automatically log in on 2nd time. but it returns bool(true) or string(0) ""

Comment: There is something different. If fiddler showed the same thing it would be working. is the same cookie sent the second time? is the cookie that is set with the first call sent on the second? Look closer.

Comment: strange thing fidler hows only one request and one response.(combined for both requests) I've added link to the code just below post in case if you can check out.

Comment: with http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9198104/index3.php this change now i get headers for second link but no body.. strange thing

Answer (score 1):

Chances are good that there is a redirect that is happening upon verification of your credentials. You can still use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` without having to actually print that to screen - is there a reason why you have it commented out?

Comment: actually there is a redirect and thats the reason i have commented

Comment: well using followlocation will redirect to some other page and that what i am trying to avoid. cause i need to call the first link just to create a session on server and set a cookie on machine