# How to login to a website using curl and PHP?

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I was trying to login to a site remotely. I have successfully done that and the landing page opens properly and I can extract all info from it. The problem is, when I click any link, the website logs me out! Earlier the link was relative to my domain, now I've changed it to the website domain but still the problem persists. I'm attaching the code for you to see how I've sent cookies.

I have executed another `curl_exec` to another URL within the site, but the website logs me off!

```
<html> 
<head> 
<base href="http://example.com/" /> 
<body> 
<?php 
$username = $_POST["uname"]; 
$password = $_POST["pass"]; 
$fields = "username=" . $username . "&password=" . $password . "&Login.x=61&Login.y=15"; 
$ch=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.SOMESITE.net/amizone/default.aspx'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "ASPSESSIONIDSQADDRBQ=OCALKIGABGLPCJLKMGIKJLLF"); //I got this exact cookiename from LiveHTTPheaders (Firefox extension)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "ASPSESSIONIDSQADDRBQ=OCALKIGABGLPCJLKMGIKJLLF"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.8) Gecko/20061025 Firefox/1.5.0.8' ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1 ); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.com/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 ); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); 
ob_start(); //the issue with the script remains with/without ob_start/ob_end_clean
$raw_data=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); //at this point im trying to get another page using curl. since i will not be using post i have set it to 0.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http:/site.net/amizone/WebForms/TimeTable/StudentTimeTableForWeek.aspx'); 
$ttable = curl_exec($ch); 
ob_end_clean(); 
echo $ttable; 
//curl_close($ch); 
//$raw_data = preg_replace('/\s(1,)/',' ',$raw_data); //clean it up 
//echo $raw_data; 
//$raw_data = stripslashes($raw_data); 
//$raw_data = explode("<strong>",$raw_data); 
//2 3 and 4 
//echo htmlentities($raw_data[4]); 
?> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Note: I have taken the cookie name from 'LiveHttpHeaders', an extension for Firefox. What am I missing?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271387/php-curl-able-to-login-into-site-but-shows-no-data-after-login this might be ur issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing with the cookiejar and cookiefile? Those are not for setting cookies, and a session variable shouldn't be hardcoded, but be obtained from the first request to the ASP web server.

You want to set the cookiejar and cookiefile to a value as per the documentation:

> **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE**     The name of the file containing the cookie data.
>   The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style
>   headers dumped into a file.
>   **CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR**  The name of a file to
>   save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a
>   call to curl_close.

So, no cookie data, but a path to a file. This way the session cookie (and other cookies) will be stored and used in successive requests.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
Even if i use something like.. (CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "tmp/cookie");
It still does the same thing..
Some people are saying that u need to use full path and not relative, could that be the issue?

Comment: Ive even tried doing this..
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); 
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
but no luck..

Comment: ive used a simple txt file name, a full absolute file path, everything. 
Do i need to add session_start(); at the top?